# The audiowaveform is not displaying for the recorded voice

Tags: flutter, audio, wave

The audiowave package is not displaying in the recorded audio. I am seeking assistance to ensure that the audiowave updates and changes dynamically while playing the audio. Does anyone know how to use flutter audiowaveform package correctly. when I try to use some other packages which is referred on youtube they are deprecated. Can anyone help with this issue?

audioplayer.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:audio_wave/audio_wave.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../../../controller/audioprovider.dart';
import 'package:audio_waveforms/audio_waveforms.dart';
import '../../../model/chat/chatdetaildata.dart';
import 'package:flutter_audio_waveforms/flutter_audio_waveforms.dart';

class AudioPlayerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final ChatMessage chatMessage;
  

  AudioPlayerWidget(this.chatMessage);

  @override
  _AudioPlayerWidgetState createState() => _AudioPlayerWidgetState();
}

class _AudioPlayerWidgetState extends State<AudioPlayerWidget> {
  final player = AudioPlayer();
  bool isPlaying = false;
  bool isAnimation = true;
  Duration duration = Duration.zero;
  Duration position = Duration.zero;

  StreamSubscription? completionSubscription;
  late Timer _timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Set up the timer to update the position every second while audio is playing
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
      setState(() {
        // Update the position only if the audio is currently playing
        if (isPlaying) {
          position = position + Duration(seconds: 1);
        }
      });
    });
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    player.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> playAudio() async {
    await player.play(UrlSource(widget.chatMessage.audioPath!));
    setState(() {
      isPlaying = true;
      isAnimation = false;
    });
    completionSubscription = player.onPlayerComplete.listen((_) {
      // Audio playback completed
      setState(() {
        isPlaying = false;
        isAnimation = true;
        position = Duration.zero;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<void> pauseAudio() async {
    await player.pause();
    setState(() {
      isPlaying = false;
      isAnimation = true;
    });
    completionSubscription?.cancel();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final audioProvider = Provider.of<AudioProvider>(context, listen: true);
    final formattedTime = audioProvider.getFormattedTime(widget.chatMessage.audioPath!);
    final remainingTimeInSeconds = audioProvider.getSecondsFromFormattedTime(formattedTime) - position.inSeconds;
    final remainingTime = audioProvider.getFormattedDuration(remainingTimeInSeconds);
    // final remainingTime = audioProvider.getFormattedDuration(
    //     remainingTimeInSeconds >= 0 ? remainingTimeInSeconds : 0);
    PlayerController controller = PlayerController();
     // final formattedTime = audioProvider.getFormattedTime();
    // print(formattedTime);
    // print(audioProvider.hashCode);
    // print(audioProvider.hashCode);
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if (isPlaying) {
          pauseAudio();
        } else {
          playAudio();
        }
      },
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight, // Align to the right (sender's side)
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8), // Add padding to the top
          child: Container(
            width: 170,
            height: 45,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 160,
                  height: 60,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), // Add border radius
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (isPlaying) {
                              pauseAudio();
                            } else {
                              playAudio();
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ),

                      
                      Expanded(
                        child: AudioFileWaveforms(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          size: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.2, 10.0),
                          playerController: controller,
                          playerWaveStyle: PlayerWaveStyle(
                            scaleFactor: 0.8,
                fixedWaveColor: Colors.white30,
                liveWaveColor: Colors.white,
                waveCap: StrokeCap.butt,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                
                //   Expanded(
                
                 
                Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 33.0, right: 18),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(width: 20,),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                           
                                // final formattedTime = audioProvider.getFormattedTime();
                                // print(formattedTime);
                              Text(remainingTime, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 8))
                            
                              
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 90,),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                           
                                
                                // final formattedTime = audioProvider.getFormattedTime();
                                // print(formattedTime);
                              Text(formattedTime, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 8))
                            
                              
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                  ),
                
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

audioprovider.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:chatapp/model/chat/chatdetaildata.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:record/record.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

import '../model/audio/recorded_audio_data.dart';

class AudioProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<ChatMessage> audioMessages = [];
  final record = Record();
  final textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  String _formattedTime = "01:00"; // Default value
  String get formattedTime => _formattedTime;

  Timer? _durationTimer;
 
  bool _isRecording = false;
  String _recordedFilePath = '';
  DateTime? _startTime; // To store the end time of recording

  DateTime? _endTime; // To store the end time of recording

  bool get isRecording => _isRecording;
  String? get recordedFilePath => _recordedFilePath;

  int _recordingDuration = 0;
  int get recordingDuration => _recordingDuration;
  
  Map<String, String> _formattedTimes = {};
  

  //  List<RecordedAudio> _recordedAudios = [];
  // List<RecordedAudio> get recordedAudios => _recordedAudios;

  Future<void> startRecording() async {
    try {
      if (await record.hasPermission()) {
        final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        final uniqueFileName = Uuid().v4(); // Generate a unique file name using uuid
        _recordedFilePath = '${directory.path}/$uniqueFileName.m4a';
        await record.start(
          path: _recordedFilePath!,
          encoder: AudioEncoder.aacLc,
          bitRate: 128000,
          samplingRate: 44100,
        );
        _isRecording = true;
        _startTime = DateTime.now();
        print('Start recording');
        notifyListeners();
        _startRecordingDurationTimer();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
    }
  }

void _startRecordingDurationTimer() {
  _durationTimer?.cancel();
  _recordingDuration = 0; // Reset recording duration at the start of recording
  _durationTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
    _recordingDuration++;
    // Update the formatted time whenever the recording duration changes
    final formattedTime = getFormattedDuration(_recordingDuration);
    if (_recordedFilePath != null) {
      setFormattedTime(formattedTime, _recordedFilePath!);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  });
}
```